# Lifecycle of ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-lifecycle

What fragment lifecycle methods (onCreate, onViewCreate, onStart) are called after you setup ViewPager with, say, 10 fragments and call setCurrentItem(9)?

Will there be any difference if you call setCurrentItem(i, false)?

Comment: To answer your second question, just read the documentation... "smoothScroll boolean: True to smoothly scroll to the new item, false to transition immediately"

Comment: The first question can easily be answered by debugging, by yourself.

Comment: @cricket_007 that doesn't answer will onStart be called for all fragments or not.

Comment: @SelçukCihan well, I tried that and I found out that onCreate, onStart etc methods are called for positions (assuming we have 11 fragments and called setCurrentItem(9, false): 0, 1, 9, 10, 8. So I was unsure if it was me who made mistake, or I just understand docs incorrectly. I supposed that if we use smoothScroll=false, 0 and 1 fragments should not be instatiated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What fragment lifecycle methods (onCreate, onViewCreate, onStart) are called after you setup ViewPager

Every lifecycle method you mentioned plus `onAttach`, `onResume`, and `onActivityStarted` are called. There is nothing about a ViewPager that affects that. Refer to [this picture](http://developer.android.com/images/fragment_lifecycle.png) to see the Fragment lifecycle.

> Will there be any difference if you call setCurrentItem(i, false)?

No, `false` does not affect the lifecycle. the only thing that `false` will do is transition immediately to the page instead of smoothly across the ViewPager.

The `onPause`, `onStop`, etc. methods may be called after you scroll out of view of a Fragment, but that was not part of your question. ..

Comment: Thank you for clarification. Albeit I have one more confusing me thing. It seems that onStart is called not for every fragment given to viewPager, when we call setCurrentItem(i, false). To be specific, it is called for 0, 1, i and 2 it's neighbors positions. Is there any way to call onStart ONLY on **i** fragment and it's neighbors, skipping others?

Comment: The reason for that is so only the current plus the neighbors are visible and you can quickly scroll one position either direction and not load more Fragments into memory at once. Why do you need to specifically target one Fragment, but skip others?

Comment: Because I want to load some information from web into fragment as soon as it's visible to user, but not before that. I want to eliminate calling onStart on fragments that are not visible (i.e. 0 and 1 positions). Is that possible?

Comment: As soon as you set the adapter for a ViewPager, Fragments 0 and 1 are loaded. I don't think you can scroll to any positions before that simply because there are no Fragments to scroll to